# How to make a If statement in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, database, model, handlebars.js

I am making a page in handlebars that has a if for every medal that you can earn. It also use a db for the user that pass in the medalProgress. For some reason no matter what i do it give me an error and does not even load the main even though it should just not render that part if there is nothing.The default valce for medalPrgress is 0 so right now i will be happy if the site just load again. I can test the other if by just changing the default value in the model.

This is the block of code that is giving me trouble:

```
            {{#if user.medalProgress == 0}}
            <p>askljfdsjklf</p>
            {{/if}}
```

This is what i have try so far:

```
{{#if medalProgress = 0}}

{{#if medalProgress == 0}}
{{#if medalProgress === 0}}

{{#if user.medalProgress = 0}}
{{#if user.medalProgress == 0}}
{{#if user.medalProgress === 0}}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure [`#if`](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#if) works as you want it to.

Comment: Handlebars does not support logical operators like `===`. If your `medalProgress` can evaluate either to `0` or a Truthy value, then you could use it like a Boolean: `{{if medalProgress}}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the HTML if "user.medalProgress" is 0, then add [`includeZero=true`](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#includezero) like this

```
{{#if medalProgress includeZero=true}}
  <p>medalProgress is true even if it is 0</p>
{{/if}}
```

If you however want to use a more complex if statement you will need to use [Sub-Expressions of Built-in Helpers](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#sub-expressions), in this example it will only render if `user.medalProgress` is 0: ([same example](https://handlebarsjs.com/playground.html#format=1&currentExample=%7B%22template%22%3A%22%7B%7B%23if%20(IfStatment%20user.medalProgress)%20%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20user.medalProgress%20is%200%5Cn%7B%7Belse%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20user.medalProgress%20is%20not%200%5Cn%7B%7B%2Fif%7D%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22partials%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22input%22%3A%22%7B%20user%3A%20%7BmedalProgress%3A%200%7D%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22output%22%3A%22%20%20user.medalProgress%20is%200%5Cn%22%2C%22preparationScript%22%3A%22Handlebars.registerHelper(%27IfStatment%27%2C%20function%20(value)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20return%20value%20%3D%3D%3D%200%3B%5Cn%7D)%3B%5Cn%22%2C%22handlebarsVersion%22%3A%224.7.7%22%7D))

```
/* Template */
{{#if (IfStatment user.medalProgress) }}
  user.medalProgress is 0
{{else}}
  user.medalProgress is not 0
{{/if}}
```

```
/* Preparation-Script */
Handlebars.registerHelper('IfStatment', function (value) {
  return value === 0;
});
```

```
/* Input */
{ user: {medalProgress: 0} }
```

The documentation of how to use Helpers can be found [here](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#helpers).